# How to deploy asp.net webapp in azure virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, azure, virtual-machine

I am quite new to azure and need a quick pointer to how to host an asp.net website in Azure VM. Thanks for your help in advance.

**A little background...** 
We were using a windows server 2012 R2 and were hosting the site in IIS 6. This was an intranet site. Now we are migrating to public cloud so that it is accessible over internet. For this we have acquired an Azure VM (Windows OS). We have installed Visual studio 2013 and SQL server 2012 here. I have installed azure core SDK too.

Here are my questions:

1. What do I use instead of IIS to host? (Because I am not able to find any related app in azure VM)
2. Do I need to buy any more licenses for the same?
3. Should I host it in IIS only and because it is in public cloud, will it be accessible over internet?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have chosen the Infrastructure as a service ( IaaS) route you have to simply replicate the setup that you have on premises.

if IIS component is not there you just have to enable it in windows features.

If you do not want to use IIS you can explore self hosted asp.net applications.

Since you have chosen the Windows server VM image and created the VM you do not need to pay for anything additional for windows license.

By default only 2 endpoints( ports) will be open in a Windows VM. 1 for remote desktop and other for powershell remoting. 
refer this post for enabling endpoints for you hosted applications. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints

Comment: Thanks much Aravind! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options basically

1. Use Azure Paas - Here you would host your existing application as a Cloud service using a web role and a Azure SQL Database. This might mean some changes to the existing application but would need less management from you. You can find the migration steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service)
2. Use Azure Iaas - This is pretty much what you are trying to do. Host your application to a VM and manage all the required software (IIS,Sql server etc) on your own. Although this option might be easier in terms of migrating your application it involves managing the infrastructure on your own. [Here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-hero-role) on how to install IIS on a Azure VM.

You don't need any additional licenses since you are paying for the VM which includes all required licenses. In case you decide to use SQL Server as Iaas you can also [use your existing SQL Server license](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-bring-your-sql-server-licenses-to-azure-vms/) when running SQL Server on an Azure VM.